# basic level maths to geometrical interpolations (trilinear, prism, pyramid, tetrahedral) - where do I start?

Tags: geometric-interpretation, computational-science

I'm attempting to read Computational Color Technology by Henry R. Kang but I only have a GCSE level understanding of maths (if even that, it was 15 years ago..). I'd like to learn about geometrical interpolations (trilinear, prism, pyramid, tetrahedral) and apply this to code my own custom image/colour manipulation tools. Can anyone help suggest where I should start in order to better understand this subject?